# G Suite: MX and DNS migration

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, dns, gmail

I've migrated DNS from GoDaddy to AWS, along with MX records. My MX record was set to my G Suite account with Gmail. After migration, I leave the same MX record on AWS as it was set on GoDaddy. My mail wasn't working for 20h - I couldn't receive or send any message. However, I didn't receive any mail about "Not delivered" status.

Few minutes ago, I've updated MX record and I received some messages.

Is it any way to recover mails which could be sent to me during 20h when DNS were wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't have the Correct MX records set, whoever tried to email you should have gotten a bounce back email that the mailbox is not reachable.

There is no way to recover as the email messages didn't reach the server.

Cheers

Comment: I think you are right. There is a chance that host will try to resend undelivered email and makes few attempts for the next few days.